# Please someone Fix this SHOW/HIDE Table Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html-table, hide, dreamweaver, show

**Please someone Fix this Javascript Code.**

This script actually reads the URL Parameter and then depending on the parameter it SHOW/HIDE's Table rows.

I found out this script on Sack Overflow but when tried it on Dreamweaver, its not working..

Please someone go through the script and fix what is wrong in it....

The Script is: There are two pages here...

First is the `First_page.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="Second_page.html?showid=tblRow14">First Row</a><br />
<a href="Second_page.html?showid=tblRow46">Second Row</a><br />
<a href="Second_page.html?showid=tblRow30">Third Row</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

and the `Second_page.html` is as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<head>
<style>
#theTable>tbody>tr { display: none; } //hide rows by default
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlVar(varName) { //returns empty string if variable name not found in URL
  if (!varName) return ''; //no variable name specified. exit and return empty string

  varName = varName.toLowerCase(); //convert to lowercase
  var params = location.search; //get URL

  if (params == '') return ''; //no variables at all. exit and return empty string

  var vars = params.split('?')[1].split('&'); //get list of variable+value strings

  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) { //check each variable
   var varPair = vars[i].split('='); //split variable and its value

   if (varPair.length > 1) { //has "=" separator

     if (varPair[0].toLowerCase() == varName) { //same variable name?
       return varPair[1]; //found variable. exit and return its value
     } //else: check next variable, if any

   } //else: is not an array. i.e.: invalid URL variable+value format. ignore it
  }
  return ''; //no matching variable found. exit and return empty string
}

function show() {
  var value = getUrlVar('showid'); //get variable value
  if (!value) return; //variable not found
  if (parseInt(value) == NaN) return; //value is not a number

  var row = document.getElementById('tblRow' + value); //get the element by ID name
  if (!row) return; //element not found

  row.style.display = 'inherit'; //set element display style to inherited value (which is visible by default)
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="show();">
<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="tblRow14"><td>row ID 14</td></tr>
  <tr id="tblRow46"><td>row ID 46</td></tr>
  <tr id="tblRow30"><td>row ID 30</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please fix it or help me in finding out a new Javascript code that works same like this does...

Please Help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter showid in the url must be an integer. Change your links in First_page.html.

```
<a href="Second_page.html?showid=14">First Row</a><br />
<a href="Second_page.html?showid=46">Second Row</a><br />
<a href="Second_page.html?showid=30">Third Row</a><br />
```

Comment: Thank you very much rocky3000 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "value" variable already has the id of the . So, just change this line:

```
var row = document.getElementById(value);
```

And it will work.